# Integrate OpenERP with external applications

Tags: python, integration, odoo

How would one go about integrating OpenERP with external applications? My team mate is developing a custom application as part of a bigger system and I need to access his application to pull some data in OpenERP (to produce reports from), how can this be achieved?

I know people have integrated OpenERP with other applications like Magneto and Quickbooks so its certainly possible but where should I start?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be achieved using the [OpenERP web services](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.1/developer/12_api.html#working-with-web-services)